# Proteus simulation problem (beginner) - "Power rails 'VCC/VDD' and 'GND' are interconnected in net GND" errors

Tags: microcontroller, pic, simulation, proteus

I'm a beginner to microcontroller programming and the Proteus simulator. I'm following this "[PIC MicroController Volume Adjuster Program(Proteus 8 Stimulation)](https://www.instructables.com/id/PIC-MicroController-Volume-Adjuster-ProgramProteus/)" Instructables project.

When I pressed the start button to start the simulation, I got the errors shown below. Can someone tell me what the problem is?

[image: schematic]

[image: error messages]

Comment: What you have done is a short circuit around SW1 and SW2. Fix the short.

Answer (score 3):

The error messages from Proteus are correct. In your schematic, **you** have shorted Vcc to Gnd.

Here is the relevant part of the original, **correct**, schematic from your [Instructables link](https://www.instructables.com/id/PIC-MicroController-Volume-Adjuster-ProgramProteus/) - it has no short between Vcc and Gnd:

[image: Original, correct, schematic]

---

Notice how **your** schematic is different in that area which I marked:

[image: Incorrect schematic]

---

The solution (as commented by *G36*) is to fix your schematic, including removing the short which you have between Vcc and Gnd.